# Как правильно сверстать линии между разбросанными маркерами списка

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```css
@media (min-width: 679px) {
  .text-block {
    width: 679px;
  }
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.text-block {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.text-block__list {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  counter-reset: num;
}

.text-block__list::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  bottom: 52px;
  left: 62px;
  width: 0px;
  border-left: 1px solid #40A06F;
}

.text-block__item {
  position: relative;
  counter-increment: num;
}

.text-block__item::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  color: #FFCD00;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-size: 30px;
  content: counter(num);
  font-weight: bold;
}

.text-block__item::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  top: 12px;
  left: 52px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}

.item__text {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 60px 40px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 881px) {
  .text-block {
    width: 881px;
  }
  .text-block__list::before {
    display: none;
  }
  .item__text {
    padding: 24px 254px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .text-block__item::before {
    top: 42px;
    left: 26px;
  }
  .text-block__item::after {
    top: 48px;
    left: 60px;
  }
  .text-block__item:nth-child(even)::before {
    left: auto;
    right: 26px;
  }
  .text-block__item:nth-child(even)::after {
    left: auto;
    right: 60px;
  }
  .item__text::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 741px;
    height: 147px;
    left: 69px;
    top: -15px;
    border-radius: 50px;
  }
  .item__text:nth-child(odd)::before {
    border-top: 1px solid green;
    border-right: 1px solid green;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="text-block">
    <ul class="text-block__list">
      <li class="text-block__item item">
        <p class="item__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus accusantium dicta dolor dolorum in laboriosam mollitia?</p>
      </li>
      <li class="text-block__item">
        <p class="item__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus accusantium dicta dolor dolorum in laboriosam mollitia?</p>
      </li>
      <li class="text-block__item">
        <p class="item__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus accusantium dicta dolor dolorum in laboriosam mollitia?</p>
      </li>
      <li class="text-block__item">
        <p class="item__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus accusantium dicta dolor dolorum in laboriosam mollitia?</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Интересует, собственно, как воплотить изображенные на картинке линии соединения маркеров.

Я пробовал это сделать через создание псевдоэлемента размером с блок текста и обрамления его в `border` необходимого цвета и изгиба, но получается криво.

Может есть правильное и не сложное решение.

Спасибо

[image: линии соединяющие маркеры списка]

Comment: Не видно, где "пробовал это сделать". А так, да, псевдоэлементы и всё.

Comment: проблему видно, если развернуть код на всю страницу (до Десктоп версии)

Comment: svg в фон для четных/нечетных, первого/последнего

Answer (score 4):

Вы правильно начали - счётчик, псевдоэлементы и нужные селекторы - это хорошо. Но, есть же ещё много разных свойств - например, `box-shadow` (вместо влияющего на всё, что ни попадя, `border`-а). Старался сделать максимально похожим и с минимумом кода. Главный минус - утолщения на скруглениях линий (не знаю, насколько это критично для Вас).

Запустите код, разверните на всю страницу, читайте текст (и небольшие комментарии в CSS):

```css
.text-block {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 0 45px;
  /* Свойства ниже - для интерактивности и наглядности */
  resize: both;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px red;
}

.text-block__list {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: text;
}

.text-block__item {
  position: relative;
  counter-increment: text;
}

.text-block__item::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 55%;
}

/* Нечётные пункты */
.text-block__item:nth-child(odd):first-child::before {
  left: 0; bottom: 0%;
  height: calc(50% - 2px);
  border-radius: 0 0 0 20px;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 1px #5c976b;
}
.text-block__item:nth-child(odd):not(:first-child):not(:last-child)::before {
  left: 0; bottom: 0%;
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 1px #5c976b, -2px -2px 1px #5c976b;
}
.text-block__item:nth-child(odd):last-child::before {
  left: 0; top: 2px;
  height: calc(50% - 2px);
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;
  box-shadow: -2px -2px 1px #5c976b;
}

/* Чётные пункты */
.text-block__item:nth-child(even):not(:last-child)::before {
  right: 0; bottom: 0%;
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #5c976b, 2px -2px 1px #5c976b;
}
.text-block__item:nth-child(even):last-child::before {
  right: 0; top: 2px;
  height: calc(50% - 2px);
  border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
  box-shadow: 2px -2px 1px #5c976b;
}

/* Нумерация и маркеры */
.text-block__item::after {
  content: counter(text);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  height: 22px; width: 22px;
  font: 28px/20px "Arial Black";
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #facb33;
}
.text-block__item:nth-child(odd)::after {
  left: 0%; transform: translate(-200%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 32px 0 1px -2px white, 32px 0 0px 0px #5c976b;
}
.text-block__item:nth-child(even)::after {
  right: 0%; transform: translate(200%, -50%);
  box-shadow: -32px 0 1px -2px white, -32px 0 0px 0px #5c976b;
}

.item__text {
  margin: 0;
  /* Отступы от линий до текста */
  padding: 15px 45px;
}
```

```html
<section class="text-block">
  <ul class="text-block__list">
    <li class="text-block__item">
      <p class="item__text">Берём за нижний правый угол и меняем размер - ничего не должно рассыпаться.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="text-block__item">
      <p class="item__text">Добиваемся появления полосы прокрутки - всё должно быть нормально.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="text-block__item">
      <p class="item__text">Количество блоков может варьироваться при необходимости - все стили и нумерация применятся автоматически.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="text-block__item">
      <p class="item__text">Блоки могут содержать произвольное количество текста или другой контент. А вот пустыми их лучше не оставлять.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="text-block__item">
      <p class="item__text">Все стили интуитивно понятны - разобраться и подстроить не составит труда.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="text-block__item">
      <p class="item__text">Остаётся привязать медиазапросы и проверить на мобильных устройствах (извините, нет возможности).</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Улыбнуло описание в тегах)